# "Dabei geht es um" vs "Es geht um"

Tags: phrase

I have come across both phrases at the start of sentences, and both apparently have the same meaning. Is there any difference between the two? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: You may have noticed that the phrases differ in that the first uses "dabei". Did you check what this word means? Because this may answer your question.

Comment: »Dabei geht es um« = »Es geht dabei um« ≠ »Es geht um« (no »dabei« in the 3rd phrase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means almost the same with the difference that the first version refers to something ("dabei") and the second version does not explicitly refer to something ("es" is more generic).

Answer (score 1):

In English it could be translated as "This is about..." and "It is about...", so it means basically the same, but with a slightly different construction.